# "Plaintiff" without an article

Tags: articles, legalese, countable-nouns

Garner's fourth edition reads *[we accord to **plaintiff** his due.](https://books.google.es/books?id=FwmQpyibKkAC&lpg=PA13&dq=%22we%20accord%20to%20plaintiff%20his%20due%22&hl=es&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=%22we%20accord%20to%20plaintiff%20his%20due%22&f=false)*

Why is this nominal indirect object used without any article at all?

OED: http://oed.com/oed2/00180661

Comment: Please add more context, and if possible a link. This sounds like legalese, where articles are dropped possibly more frequently than in headlinese.

Comment: What @Edwin said. But note [this webpage](https://www.law.cuny.edu/legal-writing/students/multilingual/grammar/articles/) titled ***Use of Articles*** from "Cuny School of Law". It uses the word ***plaintiff*** in no less than 6 different examples, ***always preceded by the definite article***. Also note that in court, ***the** judge* almost always gets an article, but ***counsel** for defence / prosecution* generally don't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [**LAW**] the lawyer or lawyers representing one party or the other in court: 
[countable] _"Does **counsel** have an objection?'' the judge asked_; 
[uncountable] _On the advice of **counsel**, I refuse to answer_. https://www.wordreference.com/definition/counsel

Comment: @GJC: That's too complicated for me! I have no idea why your first example counts as "countable", whereas the second one doesn't. And although it's obviously far less common, I have no problem with the actual ***grammar*** of pluralised [*On the advice of **counsels...***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22On+the+advice+of+counsels%22).

Comment: @FumbleFingers **http://oed.com/oed2/00180661** and **http://oed.com/oed2/00051624**

Comment: Ah: no more context is possible. I've found this article [[Masslegalhelp](https://www.masslegalhelp.org/consumer/debt/court/discovery-no-response)] in a Google search; 'When did you mail Interrogatories and Requests for Documents to Plaintiff?' is the string I followed, but every occurrence I've found in the article includes the definite article before 'plaintiff'. I'd say it's headlinese/legalese, and if in several years a count / non-count division in usages is deemed to be true here for 'plaintiff', we saw it here first. Note that here, 'plaintiff' must be the count usage as 'his' is used.

Comment: Note that I'm not saying that the anarthrous usage is the more common one in all legal documents, merely that dropping articles is, as with headlines, judged less strictly than in an A-Level essay.

Comment: @GJC: I don't see any reference to "countability" in either of those linked pages. Come to that, the only occurrence of the 5 consecutive letters **count** in the *current* OED's page for ***counsel*** is a citation from [*The **Countess** of Montgomery's Urania.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Countess_of_Montgomery%27s_Urania)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Also in that example its capital letter _C_. (Un)countable : https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/counsel_1?q=counsel

Comment: I don't understand _which_ article. The question and my observations other than the obviously general ones all concern [the] plaintiff, the sole subject of the question. I'm happy that 'counsel' [the legal usages] has both count and non-count usages.